# Multiple Querys context.Load SP O365

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I need to retrieve a lot of User PersonProperties, and i was wondering if it is possible to load it all together.

For example:

```
var userList = web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
clientContext.Load(userList);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

PeopleManager pm = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
List<PersonProperties> users = new List<PersonProperties>();

 foreach (ListItem u in userList)
 {
      var personProperties = pm.GetPropertiesFor(u.FieldValues["Name"].ToString());
      users.Add(personProperties);
 }

 clientContext.Load(users); //load all users[i].UserProfileProperties and PictureUrl
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

My app is a ProviderHosted and it is for SharePoint Online 2013

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SharePoint CSOM supports [Request Batching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798420.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you could take advantage of this feature and consider the following example that demonstrates how to submit  **two** requests to the server in order to:

- retrieve site users
- retrieve profile properties for site users

Example:

```
    //1.Load site users
    var siteUsers = ctx.Web.SiteUsers;
    ctx.Load(siteUsers);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    //2.Load user profile properties for site users
    var pm = new PeopleManager(ctx);
    var results = new Dictionary<string,PersonProperties>();
    foreach (var siteUser in siteUsers)
    {
         var personProperties = pm.GetPropertiesFor(siteUser.LoginName);
         ctx.Load(personProperties);
         results.Add(siteUser.LoginName,personProperties);
    }
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Usage

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
     var userLoginName = result.Key;
     var userProperties = result.Value;
     Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})",userLoginName, userProperties.Email);
}
```